# C# / SSIS: Need help finding the ComponentClassID for the MySQL Connector (6.4.1)

Tags: c#, mysql, ssis

I've been trying to programmatically create an SSIS package that has a MySQL Data Source for some time now and have been running into an issue figuring out how to get the appropriate ComponentClassID and ConnectionManager type to set for the source ConnectionManager:

```
ConnectionManager srcCm = pkg.Connections.Add("ADO.NET"); // <-- HALP!
srcCm.Name = srcConnectionName;

MainPipe dfTask = (MainPipe)dfTaskHost.InnerObject;
// Add the DB Source to the data flow.
IDTSComponentMetaData100 srcComp = dfTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();

srcComp.ComponentClassID = "ADO.NET:MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"; // <-- Wha?
```

When debugging this, I receive the hex error 0xC0048021, which according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345164.aspx) means "The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "%1"."

At this point, I've seen a number of different approaches to getting this connector working, but I don't seem to have the right combo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Rich

Answer (score 0):

```
Package.Connections.Add("ADO.NET:MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data, Version=6.2.5.0, Culture=netral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d");
srcComp.ComponentClassID=typeof(DataReaderSourceAdapter).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```